# How to vertical-align to x-height?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a line of text and a small image, which I am trying to align vertically within the line. My goal is to align the vertical center of the image with the x-height (or half of the height of a capital letter) from the baseline of the text. I can't figure out any way to do this. The closest thing that I know of is:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

This behavior as it is stated in the CSS 2.1 spec:

> Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent box plus half the x-height of the parent

If there were a way to remove the world "half" from that definition, I'd have what I want. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: could you post your code, please?

Comment: <html>
<body>
<div style="background-color: pink; font-family: arial; font-size: 10pt;">
A line of text with
<img style="vertical-align: middle; ">
An image
</div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, text sits on the text baseline while the image descends below that. And different browsers handle that differently.

My favorite solution is to display the image as a `background-image`, with its `background-position` set to `left center` ... you can season to taste.

Comment: Clever; I like this. The only problem with this is that I have to then style the span with a padding value dependent on the size of that image.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's the "best" answer, but I would always set the "line-height" of my text to match the height of what I'm trying to center it in.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vertical align center.

http://www.templatespoint.com/blog/2010/10/div-vertical-align-middle/

or use image as background image

background:url(bg_image.jpg) no-repeat left center;